# JS: Compare array of objects and add object to array if missing

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

Perhaps I'm over complicating this problem...

I have several arrays filled with objects that have one simple `name: numeric value` key-value paring.

I want to ensure all the arrays contain the same objects, and if they don't add an object/s to the array with a zero value.

```
array1 = [{'tool1': 24}]
array2 = [{'tool1': 2}, {'tool2': 21}, {'tool3': 1}]
array3 = [{'tool1': 23}, {'tool2': 13}, {'tool3': 2}, {'tool4': 10}]
array4 = [{'tool1': 18}, {'tool2': 29}, {'tool3': 19}, {'tool4': 10}]

// After the check and addition of objects, the final result of array1 and array2 would be:

array1 = [{'tool1': 24}, {'tool2': 0}, {'tool3': 0}, {'tool4': 0}]

array2 = [{'tool1': 2}, {'tool2': 21}, {'tool3': 1}, {'tool4': 0}]

// The other arrays would remain un-changed
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why array1 is having only 3 items? Shouldn't there be `tool4` also?

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala Yes- that was my bad. corrected.

Comment: Loop through all the arrays, and create a `Set` that contains all the object keys. The loop through all the object keys and all the arrays. If an array doesn't have an object with the specified key, add the object to the array.

Comment: BTW, arrays of objects with different keys make it really complicated to process. Why not put them all on a single object, like `{tool1: 24, tool2: 13, tool3: 2}`?

Comment: General rule of thumb: Arrays should usually contain uniform data. If you have an array of objects, they should contain the same properties.

Comment: I agree- though unfortunately working with the data received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
array1 = [{'tool1': 24}]
array2 = [{'tool1': 2}, {'tool2': 21}, {'tool3': 1}]
array3 = [{'tool1': 23}, {'tool2': 13}, {'tool3': 2}, {'tool4': 10}]
array4 = [{'tool1': 18}, {'tool2': 29}, {'tool3': 19}, {'tool4': 10}]


function myFunc(arr) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (!arr.find(element => element['tool' + i])) {
            let obj = {};
            obj['tool' + i] = 0;
            arr.push(obj);
        }
    }
}

myFunc(array1)
console.log('array1: ' + JSON.stringify(array1));
myFunc(array2)
console.log('array2: ' + JSON.stringify(array2));
myFunc(array3)
console.log('array3: ' + JSON.stringify(array3));
myFunc(array4)
console.log('array4: ' + JSON.stringify(array4));
```